# Using PyCharm-requirements.txt in virtual environment- gives an error- 'pip' has no attribute 'main'

Tags: python, pycharm

I am working in windows7. and have pycharm installed along with anaconda spyder. I have been working in anaconda spyder for very long but now I want to use pycharm as it is better and easier to create projects.

so I created a new virtual environment and started a new project. Now when I try to specify my package installs via requirements.txt I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 
2017.2.4\helpers\packaging_tool.py", line 192, in main
retcode = do_install(pkgs)
File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 
2017.2.4\helpers\packaging_tool.py", line 109, in do_install
return pip.main(['install'] + pkgs)
AttributeError: module 'pip' has no attribute 'main'
```

I need help in fixing this. Nothing online has worked and I dont know where the problem is. I am using pip version of 10.
Should I uninstall my anaconda python. is it possible that it is interfering with pycharm?
Thanks

Comment: First, is there a reason you're using PyCharm 2017.2.4 instead of 2018.1.4 (or at least 2017.2.7)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pip.main` is no longer supported, and, as of 10.0, was removed. (See [this documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#using-pip-from-your-program) on what to do instead, but that probably isn't directly relevant to you—you're just trying to use PyCharm, not write your own replacement for PyCharm…)

Anyway, any graphical package manager that was built around calling `pip.main`, as PyCharm's used to be, breaks with 10.0. IIRC, PyCharm changed its code to handle this before 10.0 even went live. However, you're using an old version of PyCharm, which doesn't have those changes.

---

The obvious solution is to update PyCharm.

If you don't have any reason to use an old version, just get the latest version (as of today, 2018.1.4) by [auto-updating](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/keep-product-up-to-date.html), or by downloading it from [the main Download page](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/).

If you need to stick with an old version for some reason, get the latest 2017.2 version (as of today, 2017.2.7) from [the Previous Releases page](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/previous.html). This should be essentially the same as the version you have, but with critical fixes backported (which hopefully includes working with pip 10, although I haven't tested that).

---

The other option is to downgrade `pip` to a pre-10.0 version.

You can specify a version as just `<10`. If you want to specify one explicitly, I think 9.0.3 should be the last-ever 9.x version, but, to be safe, check [the version history](https://pypi.org/project/pip/#history).

I don't know if downgrading `pip` with `pip` is *supposed* to work, but it actually did seem to work when I tried it on a test environment:

```
python3 -m pip install --force-reinstall 'pip<10'
```

If not, you can uninstall it and reinstall it:

```
python -m pip uninstall pip
python -m ensurepip
python -m pip install -U 'pip<10'
```

Comment: That is great explanation. I believe it is safe to upgrade pycharm as I may run into other issues elsewhere by downgrading pip. Now question for you-just to confirm- should I uninstall pycharm and then reinstall using the link you sent above or is there an easier way to just upgrade the version

Comment: @Blue PyCharm has a built-in updater. See [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/keep-product-up-to-date.html) for details. (Also added the link to the answer.)